# MultipleChoiceFilter with distinct values Django

Tags: python, django, filter

I am not able to make a multiple choice filter with checkbox in Django. I researched but couldn't find anything practical either than to use django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter.

I want to show as Checkboxes the distinct values of Category column from my Book Model (e.g.: "Fiction", "Romance", "Improvement") . Using PostgreSQL

**model**

```
class Book(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**filter**

```
class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    author = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    category = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,) #does not contain any parameters to enter any queryset or anything
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ['name', 'author', 'category',]
```

**views**

```
class SearchBooksView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "booksearch.html"
    book_list = Book.objects.all()

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    book_filter = BookFilter(self.request.GET)
    context['book_filter'] = book_filter

    return context
```

**booksearch.html**

```
<h1 class="h1"> Book Search </h1>
    <form method="get">
        {{ book_filter.form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
        {% for book in book_filter.qs %}
            <li>{{ book.name }} - {{ book.author}} - {{ book.category}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</h1>
```

Can you lend a helping hand?
Thank you!

Comment: Is it correct that you would like to list the choices in a form?

Comment: Yes, I would like to list all the distinct values from category, and let the user filter, whether it's one value or "n" values